# When Jesus was living on the Earth, was He capable of communicating in all languages?

Tags: life-of-jesus, nature-of-god, language

I am curious to know if Jesus was capable of communicating with everyone on the Earth back when He was living on the Earth. So, say for example, if a person from China had visited Israel back in 30 A.D. and he had met Jesus on a road there, would he and Jesus have been able to have a conversation in Chinese?

Or say that there had been a Native American man who had been able to row across the Atlantic Ocean in a boat in 30 A.D. and he visited Israel. Would he and Jesus have been able to have a conversation using the man's Native American language?

I'm not talking about them communicating via the Gift of Tongues, but communicating via the person's actual language. So, if there were people nearby to Jesus and the foreign person, they would have heard Jesus talking in the foreign person's language.

When Jesus was living on the Earth, was He capable of communicating with all the people on the Earth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mainstream Christianity understanding, Jesus had both divine and human natures.  In his human nature he was indistinguishable physically and culturally from a typical 1st century Jewish-born man (native of Nazareth, Galilee), speaking the languages that his countrymen would have spoken, which was primarily Aramaic, Greek (the *lingua franca* at the time), and possibly a little Latin.

So no, even if it were possible in theory that Jesus accessed his divine nature to speak Chinese, he probably wouldn't have done it, since his mission was to the Israel first (Matt 15:24), although his death was for all mankind (see the article [Why Did Jesus Say He Came Only for Israel?](https://www.thegospelcoalition.org/blogs/trevin-wax/why-did-jesus-say-he-came-only-for-israel/)).

Answer (score -1):

If you subscribe to the notion that Jesus is God and that God is omniscient, as is common, then there's no reason to think he wouldn't know any language on earth even if he didn't study or use it.

I don't subscribe to such a view, however. Neither that Jesus was God Almighty himself nor that God knows everything exhaustively (which would void the concept of freewill).

The scriptures tell us that he studied in the synagogue "And Jesus grew in wisdom and stature, and in favor with God and man" (Luke 2:52). He was a man and had to learn and grow like any other. Thus - independent of the HS - he obviously wasn't omniscient (you can't grow in wisdom if you already know everything) and more likely than not did not personally study all the languages on earth.

Comment: This is not a true representation of Trinitarian thought: "If you subscribe to the notion that Jesus is God and that God is omniscient, as is common, then there's no reason to think he wouldn't know any language on earth even if he didn't study or use it."

Comment: @MikeBorden Trinitarian thought is a very broad and self-contradicting beast. For instance: why didn’t Jesus sin? Many Trinitarians will say that Jesus couldn’t win because he’s God. This contradicts any meaningful notion of him being a man or undergoing temptation; a farce